# Merge lines with regex in Notepad++ with certain tags

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to know how I can merge lines within **Notepad++** using **regex**, with certain tags that start with the character. For example:

```
1|AAA
BBB
CCC
6|DDD
1|EEE
FFF
6|GGG
1|HHH
UUU
III
6|OOO
```

The expected result:

```
1|AAABBBCCC6|DDD
1|EEEFFF6|GGG
1|HHHUUUIII6|OOO
```

The new records start with **1|** line and end with **6|** line.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yeah, I tried to merge rows. But cannot merge with certain tags. I am just new fresher in regex. could you give me some links to learn from basic in regex? Thanks

Comment: I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: : ) Thank you so much. Junior level, of course. : D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use this:

```
\s(?=[^1])
```

[Regex Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/eA0gK6/1)

---

Also tested in Notepad++

[image]

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the answer that helped (green tick on left)

Answer (score 0):

```
\r\n(?=(?:(?!1\|)[\s\S])*?6\|)
```

You can this and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vP2zF2/3

Comment: Thank you vks. could you give me an explaination about using g(global) and m(multi-line) in Notepad++. I dont know why defining gm in notepad++. thanks.

Comment: @ZerO you dont need those in `notepadd++`.